Powershell pscustomobject в функции
Задача: необходимо изъять из массива чисел одинаковые, посчитать их количество и вернуть в виде набора пар ('число','количество').
Реализовал в следующей функции:
    function Get-PCICount($numbers, $name)
    {
        $current = $numbers[0]
        $count = 0
        $new_numbers = @()
    
        foreach($number in $numbers)
        {
            if($current -eq $number)
            {
                $count = $count + 1
            }
            else
            {
                $new_numbers += $number
            }
        }
        $tmp += [pscustomobject]@{
            $name = $current
            Count = $count
        }
        if ($new_numbers.count -ne 0)
        {
            Get-PCICount $new_numbers $name
        }
        return $tmp
    }

Данную функцию необходимо вызывать несколько раз, в связи с чем и ввёл параметр $name, однако при проверке обнаружил, что создаваемый в функции объект $tmp не только не исчезает при выходе из тела функции, но ещё и сохраняется при последующих вызовах, из-за чего запись происходит не в новый объект, а в конец предыдущего. Так как поле $name меняется от вызова к вызову, то есть, каждый раз создаётся очередной столбец в $tmp, то на выходе получается совсем печальная картина:
$PCI_width = @( 2.5, 2.5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 5)
$PCI = @( 8, 8, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 5)
$res1 = Get-PCICount $PCI_width "PCI_width"
$res2 = Get-PCICount $PCI "PCI"

$res1
$res2

PCI_width Count
--------- -----
        8     4
        5     3
      2,5     5
              1
              3
              2

Вопрос: существует ли метод очистки "временных" объектов, используемых только внутри функции? Существует ли возможность удалить или "освободить" PS_Object (пока что, я не нашёл такого)? Существует ли аналог [pscustomobject], исключающий подобную проблему?
По алгоритму: понимаю, что можно обойтись без рекурсий, но здесь это наиболее лёгкое решение. Если обойти текущую проблему не выйдет, придётся придумывать что-то новое.

Дополнение:
Переделал алгоритм под работу с циклом, и после вывода результата удаляю на него одну из ссылок, в расчёте с последующим запуск будет создан новый объект. Результат ниже, вопрос остался тот же...
function Get-PCICount($numbers, $name)
{
    $count = 0
    $tmp_array = $numbers | Sort-Object
    $current = $tmp_array[0]
    $result = for($i = 0; $i -lt $tmp_array.count + 1; $i += 1)
    {
        if($current -eq $tmp_array[$i])
        {
            $count = $count + 1
        }
        else
        {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                $name = $current
                Count = $count
            }
            $current = $tmp_array[$i]
            $count = 1
        }
    }
    Write-Output $result
    Remove-Variable result
}

$PCI_width = @(2.5, 2.5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 5)

$r1 = Get-PCICount $PCI_width "PCI"
$r1
$r2 = Get-PCICount $PCI_width "Ner"
$r2

PCI Count
--- -----
2,5     5
  5     3
  8     4
        5
        3
        4


вероятнее всего $tmp был задан до объявления функции, подробнее об областях можно почитать в документации

Благодарю за ответ. Представленный код - полный листинг программы, соответственно если $tmp где-то и объявлялся, то не в моём коде.
Так или иначе, проблема решилась добавлением к вызову функции Format-Table -AutoSize через конвейер. Понимания это решение у меня не прибавило, да и подобрал его я случайно, но текущая информация о [pscustomobject], найденная мною на форумах и офф. сайте Microsoft, увы, не помогает никак.

$tmp объявлялся не в коде, а в консоли
у меня данный код - работает так как и ожидается
format-table, меняет тип объекта, и если нужна дальнейшая работа с объектом и его свойствами, то после format-table, это будет сделать в разы сложнее

А на какой версии PS вы запускали данный код? И в результате получили две раздельных сущности, отображенные в виде таблиц? Забыл указать, что я работал через PS-ISE, то есть с поставляемой виндой версией PS: 5.1. Если вы запускали на portable, или же просто на более высокой версии PS, то, вполне вероятно, что данный код там будет работать по-другому. Во всяком случае о подобных нюансах меня предупреждали.
Так или иначе, дальнейшая обработка данных мне уже не нужна, но благодарю за предупреждение. В данный момент решение через Foramt-Table меня устраивает.

в 5.1 и запускал, ещё раз настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться с документацией об областях действия переменных.
В ISE, я уверен вы проводили эксперименты, и $tmp был объявлен ранее, потому функция его и дописывает
просто откройте новое окно Powershell и вставьте туда первый и второй листинг до вывода результатов

Сделал как вы сказали и запустил вообще на другой машине, где этого кода не было и близко. Результат такой же, как и в вопросе. Более того, экспериментируя с [pscustomobject] я пришел к выводу, что даже не связанные друг с другом таблицы, созданные в разное время и в разных частях программы, "слипаются" друг с другом при выводе. Это не особенность моего кода, а особенность powershell, о которой я не знал. Теперь знаю. Обращаться к полям объектов мне это не мешает, а как вывести их содержимое на экран корректно я уже нашел. Про области действий почитаю, благодарю.
